# ASUS FX553VE: Black screen during boot

Tags: boot, laptop

My laptop is an ASUS FX553VE.

It shows a black screen whenever I try to power it on. I can hear a click. Fan turns on but not at full speed. Power indicator LED is on. Airplane mode LED is on. HDD is spinning silently - checked with a stethoscope -, but the HDD LED indicator doesn't turn on. Battery LED is on. CapsLock LED turns on when I press the power button then turns off. LCD remains black.

**History:** Turned my laptop on successfully. After using it for some time, I closed the lid. Then opened the lid after some time, power led is ON but HDD access LED is off. Forced shutdown. Laptop battery is discharged. Tried to power it with AC power. Failed.

I have tried other things.

Cleaned my laptop internally. Reseated the RAM, HDD, fan, LED, battery, etc. Disconnected the battery and tried to run it on AC power only. Running without CMOS battery, and then putting it back. Doing a 3-2-1 discharge cycle.

Currently I'm letting it sit for the whole night. If you have any other suggestions, please share and help me.

Comment: @john nothing turns on for me to select bios settings. no key except power key works.
how will i get it to boot from my usb. i have also tried to run my laptop without hdd

Comment: @john thank you, for a response